# Python calling C: how could C send Python's line number it has been called from?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I have a Python code calling some C code (.so file).

Is there a way, from within the C code, go get the line number it has been called from at the Python side?

Comment: You'd probably have to pass the line number in from the Python side. That is, call the C function with an additional parameter whose value is `inspect.currentframe().f_lineno`.

Comment: I think you should check out SWIG: http://www.swig.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually found the `PyFrame_GetLineNumber(PyFrameObject *f)` C function, whose source is located in `frameobject.c`.